# What is the @color/cream_dark in this Tutorial?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I wanted to create a drop shadow behind a button for my app, but when I tried to do what is done here: http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2011/06/29/drop-shadow-linearlayout/, Eclipse can't find @color/cream_dark or @color/cream. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify those colors in a file named color.xml in the "values" folder which is in the "res" folder.  You can put any RGB value into this resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="cream_dark">#000000</color>
    <color name="cream">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

See this link: [color xml file description](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color)

Answer (score 1):

And you probably want to use some alpha, so that the underlying background shines through the shadow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="shadow_dark">#5000</color>
    <color name="shadow_light">#0000</color>
</resources>
```